# Change the font color inside a Picker View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uipickerview

I am in process of creating a currency converter app. The currency should be selected with a picker view, all the data is already inside. My picker view Font is currently black, but I want to have it white. How would I change the color of the font (not the background)?

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
{
    return pickerViewSource.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
{
    return pickerViewSource[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int

    price_kind = pickerViewSource[row]
    switch price_kind {
    case "USD":
        label.text = "$  " + price_kind
        rate = 1.0
    case "EUR":
        label.text = "€  " + price_kind
        rate = 0.9461
    case "GBP":
        label.text = "£  " + price_kind
        rate = 0.8017
    case "RUB":
        label.text = "₽  " + price_kind
        rate = 64.3435
    case "CNY":
        label.text = "¥  " + price_kind
        rate = 6.9137
    case "YEN":
        label.text = "¥  " + price_kind
        rate = 6.26
    case "AUD":
        label.text = "$  " + price_kind
        rate = 1.3498
    case "CAD":
        label.text = "$  " + price_kind
        rate = 1.3483
    default:
        label.text = "$  " + price_kind
        rate = 1.0


    }
```

Comment: **picker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white** Where **picker** is reference of your UIPIcker object.

Answer (score 2):

To change the text inside the `UIPickerView` use [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsattributedstring):

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
    let str = pickerData[row]
    return NSAttributedString(string: str, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use attributedTitleForRow and NSAttributedString

**Please refer below code.**

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "some string", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor()])
    return attributedString
}
```

**If you want each row with different color, then use below code.**

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
        var attributedString: NSAttributedString!

        switch component {
        case 0:
            attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Zero", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor()])
        case 1:
            attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "One", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor()])
        case 2:
            attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Two"), attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor()])
        default:
            attributedString = nil
        }

        return attributedString
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly! This was my first question on here and I got such nice answers right away, that's awesome thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome. when someone puts clear question with code and possible image that makes easier for other to answer well. you did well. Well you have to accept any of the answer.

Comment: But how to change the Color of the text at a  particular index selected in Picker View??

Comment: @SwiftyCodes There is NSAttributedString, So you can change font color, font face etc.